# why to use public modifier in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I want some info to prepare the first servlet program.

Can anyone let me know that why we declare the userdefined class as public in servlet as well as `init()`, `service()` and `destroy()` also as public.

Can we use other access modifiers then which are they? Why to use only public modifiers?

Answer (score 2):

We have to declare servlet class and the methods init, service and destroy as public because the server should be able to access these. This is very similar to the main method declaring with the access modifier public.

Another reason is in `HttpServlet` and in `GenericServlet` classes, these three methods are public whose access level you can not reduce in inherited classes.

Comment: Only public members are accessible by outside world. protected members are accessible only in the sub classes.

Comment: @DwB You are right. Only service method is public. we can make other methods protected. In the question it was asked only about three methods init, service and destroy which should be public. Please check again.

Answer (score 1):

They can be protected as well. Look at `HttpServlet` - all these methods are protected there. The entry-point to the servlet is the `service(..)` method - it is the only one that is potentially required to be public (but I don't know of such requirement - the container can invoke the service method with reflection)

Comment: But if you use reflection then the scope doesn't really matter anyway.Right?

Comment: yes. So they can be protected. They usually aren't, because you normally don't need them to be.