# Http status 500 Error instantiating servlet class

Tags: java, servlets

I'm using Tomcat8 server and i'm getting following error.

[image: After deployment]

[image: Project Explorer]

It's url is `http://localhost:8080/WeatherWebApp` When i'm submitting the details then it's giving this error.
Here is WeatherServlet.java class

```
package org.akshayrahar;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class WeatherServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    WeatherServlet(){

    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("again");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.println("akshay rahar");
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

}
```

Here is web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee">
  <display-name>WeatherWebApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>WeatherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CurrentWeather</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is index.html file too:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Weather App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script >
      function initMap() {
        var input =document.getElementById('pac-input');

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyACZhmkSaIz436Dt3kHt_cVEYKN-gHzfYo&libraries=places&callback=initMap"async defer></script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <h1>Find weather of any city in the world</h1>
        <h2>Enter City Name</h2>

        <form  id="form" action="CurrentWeather" method="GET">
        <input id="pac-input" type="text" name="cityname">
        </form><br>

        <div class="button1">
        <button type="submit" form="form" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I've also mentioned stylesheet.css file in comment. Please check it.

Comment: Can we see your WeatherServlet class?

Comment: you need to config that servlet in `web.xml`

Comment: I've done that part too.

Comment: I'm also mentioning web.xml file.

Comment: body{
    background-color: black; 
}

h1,h2{
    color: white;
    font-family:  Garamond;
    text-align: center;
}

form{
    text-align: center;
}

.button1{
    text-align: center;
}

button{
        color:white;
    background-color: grey;
    font-family: Georgia;
}

Comment: Servlet class name is Full name. Must be org.akshayrahar.WeatherServlet  in web.xml

Comment: It's not working sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error shows that Tomcat is unable to create an instance of your `WeatherServlet` class.

You should make its constructor and other methods `public` too. You can even make use of the default constructor by removing the less accessible constructor:

```
public class WeatherServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public WeatherServlet(){

    }
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("again");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.println("akshay rahar");
    }
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

}
```

Comment: @Peter  Maybe he is trying to learn this should be a supportive environment for newbies.  The reason you need to make it public is answerd. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117331/why-to-use-public-modifier-in-servlet)

Answer (score 2):

Please provide a fully qualified class name on your web.xml. I was facing a similar issue and this is what fixed it.

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.akshayrahar.WeatherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CurrentWeather</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```